# trying to post data into table with php & sql - getting "Notice: Undefined index:..."

Tags: php, sql

Here's the html:

```
<form action="php/buzz_data.php" method="get">

    <div>Image: <input type="text" name="buzz_img" size="30" /></div>
    <div>Link: <input type="text" name="buzz_link" size="30" /></div>
    <div>Description:  <textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="buzz_desc"></textarea></div>
    <div>Title: <input type="text" name="buzz_title" size="30" /></div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" value="Clear" />

</form>
```

Here's the php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ubook247", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO buzz_data (buzz_page_title, buzz_img, buzz_link, buzz_desc, buzz_title)
VALUES
('$_POST[buzz_page_title]','$_POST[buzz_img]','$_POST[buzz_link]','$_POST[buzz_desc]','$_POST[buzz_title]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

and here's the result:

Notice: Undefined index: buzz_img in C:\wamp\www\ubook247\php\buzz_data.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: buzz_link in C:\wamp\www\ubook247\php\buzz_data.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: buzz_desc in C:\wamp\www\ubook247\php\buzz_data.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: buzz_title in C:\wamp\www\ubook247\php\buzz_data.php on line 12

1 record added

The db and table are both correctly set up as a new record was created, it just didn't add the data from the inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action="php/buzz_data.php" method="get">
```

You are using `GET`, so access the values from the `$_GET[]` variable, not from `$_POST[]`. Or you can change the method to `"post"`.

Also, say hello to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)!

Comment: That makes all kinds of sense. Oh, and Bobby Tables says, "Hi," and wonders when he can have his lawn mower back. Thanks, cularis.

Comment: He can have his lawn mower when I can have my Students table!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should also try

```
    $sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO buzz_data (buzz_page_title, buzz_img, buzz_link, buzz_desc, buzz_title)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
$_POST["buzz_img"],$_POST["buzz_link"],$_POST["buzz_desc"],$_POST["buzz_title"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array indices also should be in quotes, try something like

VALUES('{$_GET['buzz_page_title']}', '{$_GET['buzz_img']}', ...

in the `VALUE` clause.